# Can I have an Observable that emits values to be used by another Observable?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I am new to rx-java and may not be using it correctly, but this is what I am trying to do:

I have an `Observable<String>` that stores some data in an external database and emits a String which is the path or key to the data that was stored.

I have a second `Observable<Boolean>` that takes a String and puts it on a queue and emits whether that operation was successful.

I want to 'chain' these two Observables such that when the `Observable<String>` emits a path, the `Observable<Boolean>` puts it on a queue and returns whether it was successful. I want to end up with a single Observable that performs both of these operations.

I haven't been able to find any API methods that let me do what I want so I am starting to think that I am not using rx-java properly. It seems like I need to take my `Observable<String>` and call .map() to turn it into an `Observable<Boolean>`, but by doing this I am not able to use my original `Observable<Boolean>` other than by just running it as a blocking method inside of map(), but it may as well just be a Callable at that point.

edit: seems like I should probably be using Singles rather than Observables as my Observables only need to emit one value before completing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `flatMap` is what you are looking for.

So you have:

```
Observable<String> data;
```

and method

```
Observable<Boolean> putOnQueue(String path);
```

Then you could do:

```
Observable<Boolean> result = data.flatMap(path -> putOnQueue(path));
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for.